# ¿Por qué me lanza un error la coma al intentar insertar datos en Sql Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-18c

[image: Error]Cuando intento crear un insert en la tabla `región` me tira un error en la coma al querer ingresar múltiples datos, no sé si la sintaxis en Oracle 18c es diferente, pero no he encontrado la solución en ningún lado.

```
CREATE TABLE region (
    id_re   NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
    nombre  VARCHAR2(75) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO region (id_re,nombre)
VALUES
    (1,'Arica y Parinacota'),  --el error lo marca en esta coma
    (2,'Tarapacá'),
    (3,'Antofagasta'),
    (4,'Atacama'),
    (5,'Coquimbo'),
    (6,'Valparaiso'),
    (7,'Metropolitana de Santiago'),
    (8,'Libertador General Bernardo OHiggins'),
    (9,'Maule'),
    (10,'Ñuble'),
    (11,'Biobío'),
    (12,'La Araucanía'),
    (13,'Los Ríos'),
    (14,'Los Lagos'),
    (15,'Aysén del General Carlos Ibáñez del Campo'),
    (16,'Magallanes y de la Antártica Chilena');
```

El error que obtengo es:

```
Error SQL: ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
```

Comment: Pon tu código como texto

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour], para comenzar. Copie le texto que pusiste en la -no respuesta- le dí [edit] a la pregunta y lo pegué, formateándolo como texto. Te invito a darle clic en [edit] para ver como se hace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle no soporta cláusulas `values` con más de un registro. El mensaje de error es claro, oracle espera que después de cerrar el paréntesis termine la sentencia, bien con un `;` o que sea el fin del script.

No te queda de otra que *re-escribir* tu script con una sentencia `insert` por cada registro que quieres agregar:

```
INSERT INTO region (id_re,nombre) VALUES (1,'Arica y Parinacota');
INSERT INTO region (id_re,nombre) VALUES (2,'Tarapacá');
INSERT INTO region (id_re,nombre) VALUES (3,'Antofagasta');
INSERT INTO region (id_re,nombre) VALUES (4,'Atacama');
--etc
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes escribir cada comando **insert** de forma individual:

```
insert into tabla(campo1,campoN) values(value1, valueN);
```

Es decir por cada registro que desees añadir debes hacer un comando **insert**.

Ahora bien, hay un caso especial, digamos que tienes dos tablas, **region1** y **region2**, ambas con la misma estructura y quieres pasar ciertos registros de **region1** a **region2**. En este caso puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
insert into region1(id, nombre)
select id, nombre
from region2;
```

Lo que se hace aquí es seleccionar todos los campos de la tabla **region2** e insertarlos en la tabla **region1**.

Este **select** puede ser tan complejo como desees, ya que puede incluir cláusulas **where**, **orderby**, **groupby**, es decir todo lo que lleva una consulta.

**Oracle** también tiene otro comando muy poderoso llamado **merge**, que combina en un solo comando operaciones de **insert**, **delete** y **update**, puedes investigar más en internet si lo deseas.